# Can I see the history of redux actions in my react app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

How can I view the history of all redux actions that changed the state of my app? Can it be viewed with a bash command, or in Google Chrome dev tools?

The screenshot of the thing I wanna see is below

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just install redux-devtools chrome extension:[redux-devtools](https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension)

It shows actions, changes in state etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can install [redux-devtools](https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension), a Chrome extension, which will enable you not only to view the history of operations, but also to travel in time, i.e. undo, redo and alter some of the actions, which is great for debugging.